# Coding a program that tells be how many observations get a 6 after 100, 1000,10000 rolls

Tags: r

Trying to create a code that gives me the the theoretical probability as well as the simulation estimate of the chances in a game where a person rolls a die 4 times, if they would roll a 6 and prints the difference between them.However, my code is not running with R not recognizing the function.

Comment: `sample(1:6, size = 4, replace = TRUE)` is a better way to simulate 4 dice rolls.

Comment: Just another suggestion, you're not using this part `total<-obs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a more code-efficient way of doing this.

This uses `replicate()`. Note that this is not faster than your solution.

```
set.seed(123)
#this function just simulates the 4 rolls, and finds if any() is 6
my_rolls <- function(n){
  rolls <- sample(1:6, size = n, replace = T)
  any(rolls == 6) # number of 6s in a single roll
}

# now we replicate the 4-rolls r times
r <- 10
res <- replicate(r, my_rolls(4)) # simulate r times the rolls
#print(res)
#[1] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Now lets find the difference:

```
theor <- (1-(5/6)^4)
emp_prob <- sum(res)/r

emp_prob-theor
#[1] 0.1822531
```

More simulations:

```
r <- 100000
res <- replicate(r, my_rolls(4))
emp_prob <- sum(res)/r
emp_prob-theor
```

---

Everything could be wrapped inside a `my_sim()` function, easier to call:

```
my_sim <- function(r, rolls=4) {

  res <- replicate(r, my_rolls(n=rolls))

  emp_prob <- sum(res)/r

  emp_prob-theor # we return just the difference as an example
}

my_sim(r=10, rolls=4)
#[1] -0.1177469
```

Answer (score 0):

You are  missing a bracket in your function:

```
sixes_rep <- function(n=4, r){
  obs=0
  for (i in 1:r){
    if (any(ceiling(6*runif(n)) == 6)){
      obs=obs+1
      total<-obs
    } 
    # n is the number of dice
    # r is the number of replicates (capital N in the text)
    obs <-(obs/r)

    theor <- (1-(5/6)^n)
    difference <- obs-theor


    cat("Theoretical prob of at least one six in", n, "dice is:", theor, "\n")
    cat("Empirical prob of at least one six after", r,"replications is:", obs, "\n")
    cat("the difference is", difference ,"\n")
    return(difference)
  }
}
```